# AngularJS 1.x redirect to app url scheme

Tags: angularjs

I want to redirect users back to the mobile app from the controller (as opposed to a href link).

I've tried the following:

```
$location.url(`appname://app/verify/${this.access_code}`);
$location.path(`appname://app/verify/${this.access_code}`);
$window.location.href =`appname://app/verify/${this.access_code}`;
```

Because there is my appname:// instead of http://, it's treating it as an unassigned route and routing to my 404 page.

If I have a button on the page linked to  appname://app/verify/${this.access_code} it works but I'd like to programmatically redirect the user.

Just wondering if anyone with a similar issue was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding the app scheme to the $compileProvider href whitelist fixed the issue with $window.location.href

```
angular.module('app', []).config(($compileProvider) => {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|appname):/);
}
```